# Checking an array list of strings for substring

Tags: java, arrays, methods, string-comparison

I need to write a public method that takes an array of strings and checks to see if there are any strings in the array that contain the substring or string "nine". I wrote a method to check for "nine" but I'm stumped for the substring.

```
public static boolean doesFive ( String [] input ) {

    boolean rez = false;
    String n = "nine";

    for( int i = 0; i < inputArray.length - 1; i++ ) {
      if( inputArray[i].equals(n) ) {
       rez = true;
      }      
    }   

    return rez;

    }
```

Comment: Have you read the javadoc for `String` class? There's a `contains` method in there.

Answer (score 1):

Use [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead of `equals`.

From the Javadoc:

> **contains**
>
> public boolean contains(CharSequence s)
>
> **Returns:**
>
> true if and
> only if this string contains the specified sequence of char values.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> s - the sequence to search for Returns: true if this
> string contains s, false otherwise
>
> **Throws:**
>
> NullPointerException - if s
> is null
>
> **Since:**
>
> 1.5

Comment: Thanks, not sure why I thought to over complicate that.

Answer (score 1):

u can use contains

```
for( int i = 0; i < inputArray.length - 1; i++ ) {
  if( inputArray[i].contains(n) ) {
   rez = true;
  }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- you can use contains to check if a given string contains "nine".
- in your for loop inputArray.length - 1 means if array size is 3 then 
  it will run for i = 0,1 but not for 2.
- You can break after the first match if you only want to check if any of
  the given strings contains    "nine".
- And try to choose descriptive names for methods variables etc. that
  make sense in your given context it will help you and your fellow
  coders understand code better.

  public static boolean doesFive ( String [] inputArray) {

  ```
  boolean rez = false;
  String n = "nine";

  for( int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++ ) {
    if( inputArray[i].contains(n) ) {
     rez = true;
     break;
    }      
  }   

  return rez;

  }
  ```